# Where can I buy or download icons for use in Network diagrams

Tags: icon, illustration

I need to create a large amount of network/it diagrams for a client but I don't want to draw them all from scratch. Is there any where I can buy some really nice icons of servers / routers / phones etc. Isometric, 3d or flat is fine.

[image]

Comment: The Noun Project has plenty of nice icons, especially if you're looking for flat or minimal iconography.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a [Google](https://www.google.com/) search for icons you get a huge list, did you do a Google search?  Have you tried entering keywords?  Such as `server, networking, IT, computers` on the icon sites?

- [Icon Archive](http://www.iconarchive.com/%E2%80%8E)
  [image]
- [Icon Finder](https://www.iconfinder.com/)
  [image]
- [Dry Icons](http://dryicons.com/%E2%80%8E)
  [image]
- [Icon Search Engine](http://findicons.com/%E2%80%8E)
  [image]